# Is it illegal for a school to take away a student's holiday break because they are bisexual?

Tags: school

So, My friend Zoey (Im going to call her Zoey, For the sake of privacy), Had joined a new school recently, from what I understand. They had taken her Thanksgiving and Christmas Breaks under the reason of "She is too new and must catch up on work". She has no work missing, and nothing from before she joined. I have a feeling they are doing this for discriminatory Reasons, because she is Bisexual. Is this illegal?

Comment: What jurisdiction was this (country, state)?  The answer would depend on the state of LGBT discrimination law.

Comment: Legal issues are resolved taking into account facts, not feelings. What facts do you have to support your suspicion? How on Earth would the school even know of her sexuality?

Comment: In what way are they taking her breaks? Are they forcing her to come to school in the holidays when no other students are there?

Comment: I think Zoey should request (from whoever decided that) a list of the work she must catch up. Preferably in a document that states that's the work she must catch in order to have her break. That is unlikely to be stated directly by the teacher(?), but could be implicit by wording the request.

Comment: Are other LGBT students forced to work over the holidays?

Comment: Is it "she" or is it "they"? You seem to use the latter once, but the former several times.